# Use Google Search to search for an attribute in a Recipe Rich Snippet

Tags: google-search, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

A lot of sites with recipes use http://schema.org/ markup, e.g.,

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "cookTime": "PT0M",
  "datePublished": "2008-03-22",
  "description": "Lothars beste N&amp;uuml;rnberger Elisenlebkuchen, ein sehr sch&amp;ouml;nes Rezept mit Bild aus der Kategorie Kekse &amp;amp; Pl&amp;auml;tzchen. 602 Bewertungen: &amp;Oslash; 4,8. Tags: Backen, Kekse, Weihnachten",
  "image": "http://static.chefkoch-cdn.de/ck.de/rezepte/101/101059/850506-960x720-lothars-beste-nuernberger-elisenlebkuchen.jpg",
  "recipeIngredient": [
    "6  Ei(er) ",
    …
```

How can I search for pages with JSON-LD code in the webpage that are using this schema (e.g. identified by `"@context": "http://schema.org"` in combination with `"@type": "Recipe"`) or maybe by an attribute `recipeIngredient`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Search](https://www.google.com/) doesn’t offer an operator that would allow you to search for (Schema.org) types or property values.

(Related: [Google CSE](https://cse.google.com/cse/) allows you to create a custom search engine that only searches in pages with Schema.org `Recipe` markup.)

Comment: Is there any search engine where schema.org types can be used to filter results?